# Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91) error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that was working earlier, but is now showing an error:

```
Sub AttachLabelsToPoints()

   'Dimension variables.
   Dim Counter As Integer
   Dim ChartName As String
   Dim xVals As String

   ' Disable screen updating while the subroutine is run.
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Store the formula for the first series in "xVals".
   xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula

   'Extract the range for the data from xVals.
   xVals = Mid(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, ","), xVals, _
      Mid(Left(xVals, InStr(xVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
   xVals = Left(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, "!"), xVals, ",") - 1)
   Do While Left(xVals, 1) = ","
      xVals = Mid(xVals, 2)
   Loop

   'Attach a label to each data point in the chart.
   For Counter = 1 To Range(xVals).Cells.Count
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).HasDataLabel = _
         True
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.Text = _
     Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value
   Next Counter

End Sub
```

The error is specifically around the `xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula` statement. When I put a `Set` in front of it, it just asks for an object.

Would anyone be able to help me on what's wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `Formula` if you set a breakpoint there?

Comment: what do you expect the Series 1 formula to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the chart you want to work with is the actual chart that **is active** on the worksheet.

Place this code before you set 'xVals` and adjust as needed.

```
Dim c As ChartObject
Set c = Sheets("Sheet6").ChartObjects("Chart 1") 'change to your chart name
c.Activate

'Store the formula for the first series in "xVals".
xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
```

Generally, it's bad practice to use `Active` anything (Chart / Sheet / Cell / etc.), but when manipulating charts, that's the only way AFAIK. I don't know of a way to work directly with the object in this way. If someone else does, perhaps they can post a better answer.